# Does an array of vectors form a 2D vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, graph

Does the following statements form a 2D vector?

Also mention the dimensions of the vector if it does. Is there another way of declaring a global 2D vector?

Statements:

```
vector<int> *adj;
adj = new vector<int>[number_of_nodes];
```

The above statements have been used for declaration of a global adjacency matrix for a graph.

It seems the question isn't clear to much of you. I want to declare a global adjacency list using vectors such that I can use direct addition of edges in graph like v[a].push_back(b). For that, I have to specify first dimension of vector while declaring which I don't have until the main is executed.

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` is what you're looking for.

Comment: And even that isn't what you really want if you need the data to be contiguous.

Comment: @DeiDei I'm aware of that but I have to declare the vector globally for an adjacency list such that I can use v[a].push_back(b). So I have to specify the first dimension of vector while declaring.

Comment: Declare vector < vector <int > > v globally and then use v.resize(number_of_nodes)  in main function. That'll solve my problem of using [] operator with vectors. This was the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Seems the community here thinks itself much more advanced for these basic concepts or maybe they are in a habit of downvoting without even understanding the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but it gives similar behaviour. So what you have created is a pointer to an array of vectors. So you will end up with this:

```
adj[0] = []
adj[1] = []
...
adj[number_nodes] = []
```

and doing a `push_back` is a legitimate way to add to the vectors:

```
adj[0].push_back(some_num) -->  adj[0] = [some_num]
```

**But this is a terrible way to approach this! Why?**

- You are using raw memory that you will have to manage and make sure you delete.
- You cant use any of the awesome `std::vector` functionality on the first dimension of the matrix.
- There is no good way to figure out the size of the vector unless you know about the variable number_of_nodes.
- ... A long list, but you get it.

You can already see that a `std::vector` can be used as a 1D matrix. So use 2 vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> Matrix2D;
```

If you need an initial size in some dimension then you can do this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> Matrix2D(number_of_nodes, std::vector<int>());
```

Or this:

```
Matrix2D.resize(number_of_nodes);
```

Or if that size is fixed at compile time then you could even do this:

```
const int number_of_nodes = 10;
std::array<std::vector<int>, number_of_nodes> Matrix2D;
```

Or go extra big and get a library for Matrix use like [Eigen.](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't aware of the size while declaring. Resize() is the solution. Thanks.

Comment: One more thing, in second statement we write <int>. Doesn't that mean that the vector we are creating is entitled for holding integer values and not other vectors?

Comment: adj = new vector<int>[number_of_nodes];
It says vector holds int values right?

Comment: @Aman, Yes, the vector at each point in the array pointed to by `adj` holds vector<ints>'s, as does each vector at the index x in the vector Matrix2D that i have presented.

Comment: Isn't it such that each of the cells of the array pointed by adj hold a vector of size number_of_nodes ?

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks for the help

Comment: What is the benefit of using `Matrix2D(number_of_nodes, std::vector<int>());` as opposed to just `Matrix2D(number_of_nodes);`?

Comment: @Jonas, other than clarity that you know what you are doing, none.